# ngx bootstrap dropdown not showing items with ngFor Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, ngx-bootstrap

As the title says I can make the dropdown items to be display when using ngFor

*visual results*

[image]

*Inspected element*

[image]

**Html**

```
        <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let item of menu">
          <button
            class="btn btn-warning btn-flat"
            [routerLink]="['/', item.name]"
            *ngIf="item.submenu.length === 0"
          >
            {{ item.name | link | titlecase }}
          </button>
          <div
            class="btn-group"
            dropdown
            [autoClose]="true"
            *ngIf="item.submenu.length > 0"
          >
            <button
              id="button-animated-menu"
              dropdownToggle
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-warning btn-flat dropdown-toggle"
              aria-controls="dropdown-animated-menu dropdown"
            >
              {{ item.name | titlecase }}
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <div
              id="dropdown-animated-menu"
              *dropdownMenu
              class="dropdown-menu"
              aria-labelledby="button-animated-menu"
            >
              <li *ngFor="let k of item.submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/', k.name]">
                  {{ k.name | link | titlecase }}
                </a>
              </li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private alert: AlertService
  ) {}
  menu: Menu[] = this.authService.menus;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.menu);
  }
}
```

**UPDATED**

**AuthService**

```
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrlLogIn;
  private USER: UserDetails;
  jwthelper = new JwtHelperService();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get roles(): string[] {
    return this.USER.authorities;
  }

  get menus(): Menu[] {
    return this.USER.menu;
  }

  login(data: any) {
    return this.http
      .post(this.baseUrl, data)
      .pipe(
        map((response: Token) => {
          if (response) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem(
              '_token',response.refresh_token);
            this.USER = this.jwthelper.decodeToken(response.access_token);
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

I've tried different approache, but what I can see, it's a bug of some sort, due to the elements are rendered in the html, but the dropdown is not taking their heights.

Any ideas?

Thanks before hand...

Comment: Are you sure this.authService.menus is already set? Where does it come from?

Comment: @MikeOne I updated with the AuthService

Comment: So it is async. Any change menus (or user) simply isn’t set yet?

Comment: @MikeOne no, in fact when I assign a fix height to the dropdown class every things work fine, and the menu is there by the time the pages loads, the problem is I can't work with a fix hight due to each menu has different amount of items

Comment: Right. So the items are there. It seems purely a styling issue then? I guess the best way to get help is to create a stackblitz that shows the issue..?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by `MikeOne` I started making a stackblitz project, and after finishing it everything worked just fine, but then I realised that the project in stackblitz had the `ngx-bootstrap@5.6.0` version while mine was `ngx-bootstrap@5.5.0` I thought it was a small issue but I tried anyways and surprisedly it worked.

So the changes were

**Updating the packages**

from

[image]

to

[image]

**Changing the imports**
[image]

The import way from the left side of the previous picture for some reason didn't work anymore, after checking the modules folder, it seems the ngx-bootstrap.ts main file was delete in the lastest version, that's why I had to change the import to the way of the right side of the picture